# How to use polylinedacorator with react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have created polyline using react-leaflet, I want to show direaction on polyline using polylinedacorator.But I don't know how to do that with react-leaflet. I found multiple examples with leaflet, but not with react-leaflet

```
const polyline = [[51.505, -0.09], [51.51, -0.1], [51.51, -0.12]]

export default class VectorLayersExample extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map center={center} zoom={13}>
       <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a 
            href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
            contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    <Polyline color="lime" positions={polyline} />
    </Map>
 )
 }
```

Can any one tell me how to use polylinedacorators with above code

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Leaflet.PolylineDecorator`](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) could be integrated with `React-Leaflet` as follows:

a) install `leaflet` and `leaflet-polylinedecorator` packages: `npm i leaflet leaflet-polylinedecorator`

b) once installed, the following component demonstrates how to utilize `Polyline`  component with `L.polylineDecorator`:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Polyline, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-polylinedecorator";

const PolylineDecorator = withLeaflet(props => {
  const polyRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const polyline = polyRef.current.leafletElement; //get native Leaflet polyline
    const { map } = polyRef.current.props.leaflet; //get native Leaflet map

    L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
        patterns : props.patterns
    }).addTo(map);
  }, []);
  return <Polyline ref={polyRef} {...props} />;
});
```

**Usage**

```
function MyMap(props) {
  const { center, zoom } = props;

  const polyline = [[57, -19], [60, -12]];

  const arrow = [
    {
      offset: "100%",
      repeat: 0,
      symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
        pixelSize: 15,
        polygon: false,
        pathOptions: { stroke: true }
      })
    }
  ];


  return (
    <Map center={center} zoom={zoom}>
      <TileLayer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      <PolylineDecorator patterns={arrow} positions={polyline} />
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Comment: I made a separate question about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143284/how-to-use-leaflet-polylinedecorator-in-react-16-4-1 . Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: same here react-leaflet 4 has no withLeaflet module. @vadminGremyachev