# polylinedacorator with react leaflet 4

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline, polyline-decorator

I am trying to include arrows to the Polyline in react-leaft. For that I am using `polylinedecorator` plugin. There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411133/how-to-use-polylinedacorator-with-react-leaflet/56431136) on this platform. However, it uses `withLeaflet` module which is not supported in react-leaflet 4.0. How can I make it run without using 'withLeaflet'.
I have tried to implement it with the hooks. However, it does not work and need some assistance, how can I make it run.

```
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
   const polylineRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const arrow = [
{
  offset: "100%",
  repeat: 0,
  symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
    pixelSize: 15,
    polygon: false,
    pathOptions: { stroke: true }
  })
}];


useEffect(()=>{
    L.polylineDecorator(polylineRef.current,{
      patterns: arrow
    })
}, [polylineRef]);

return (

  <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{height: 'calc(100% - 30px)'}}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    />
    {currentData?.movingActors.map(line =>(<Polyline key={line.id} 
    positions={[line.startLocation, line.endLocation] } ref={polylineRef} 
    color={modeColor(line.mode)}
    />  
    ))}
  </MapContainer>
</>);}
```

---

CHANGES MADE TO THE ACCEPTED ANSWER TO MAKE IT RUN

```
function PolylineDecorator({ patterns, polyline,color }) {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

   L.polyline(polyline, {color}).addTo(map);  // added color property
    L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      patterns,
      
    }).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);
 
  return null;
}


 {currentData?.movingActors.map(line =>(<PolylineDecorator key={line.id} patterns ={arrow} polyline={position}  color = {modeColor(line.mode)} />) ) }   //here I used color parameters to dynamically add colors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a custom react functional component that returns null and has a `useEffect` with the code to initialize the plugin:

```
function PolylineDecorator({ patterns, polyline }) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    L.polyline(polyline).addTo(map);
    L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      patterns
    }).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
```

and then use it like:

```
<MapContainer...>
      <TileLayer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      <PolylineDecorator patterns={arrow} polyline={polyline} />
 </MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-polylinedacorator-with-react-leaflet-v-4-x-dscq7e?file=/src/App.js:770-1022)

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer I was able to change my code. However, as you can see in the new edition of my post, that I am assigning color dynamically. I am able to change the color of the polyline, but arrowhead color is still the default. I am not able to access the property as it gives me a typescript error. For example when I am trying to access the property "arrow.forEach((line) => {line.symbol.pathOptions})", the typescript error I get is "Property 'pathOptions' does not exist on type 'ArrowHead". Can you help on that as well?

Comment: Please ask this on a new thread because it's a different question

Comment: Please check here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815727/change-the-color-of-the-l-symbol-arrowhead-in-typescript-leaflet