# Change the color of the L.Symbol.arrowhead in typescript Leaflet

Tags: typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline, polyline-decorator

I am implementing L.symbol.arrowhead to show arrows on polyline by using polyline-decorator plugin. I am able to dynamically change the polylines color, however, I am not able to dynamically change the color of the arrows. I am using react-leaflet with typscript.

```
function PolylineDecorator({ patterns, polyline,color }) {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
   L.polyline(polyline, {color}).addTo(map);  // added color property
    L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      patterns,
    }).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);
 
  return null;
}

const arrow = [
{
  offset: "100%",
  repeat: 0,
  symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
    pixelSize: 15,
    polygon: false,
    pathOptions: { stroke: true }
  })
}];


 {currentData?.movingActors.map(line =>(<PolylineDecorator key={line.id} patterns ={arrow} polyline={position}  color = {modeColor(line.mode)} />) ) }   //here I used color parameters to dynamically add colors
```

When I try to access the pathOptions via

```
arrow.forEach((line) => {line.symbol.pathOptions})
```

the typescript error I get is

> "Property 'pathOptions' does not exist on type 'ArrowHead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using Arrowhead plugin. It is much easier as it takes the same color as that of the polyline.

So my new solution looks like

```
function PolylineDecorator({polyline,color }) {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
  var x = L.polyline(polyline, {color}).arrowheads({ size: '5%' });
  x.addTo(map);
  }, [map]);
 
  return null;
}


 {currentData?.movingActors.map(line =>(<PolylineDecorator key={line.id} polyline={position}  color = {modeColor(line.mode)} />) ) }
```

However, if someone else has made it work with L.symbol.arrowhead then please update it here for others.